# Formvalidation.io – TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, formvalidation.io

I'm having some issues with Formvalidator.io, and my guess is that it has something to do with my code nesting...

I'm getting an error on line 972 in code example below. The error is as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
```

Line 972 in the code is:

```
var selected_department_id = $('#departmentName').select2('data').id;
```

The error fires when I try to validate the form.

On `console.log(selected_department_id)` I get the intended result, so I know the function is declared and working as intended.

Does anyone have any suggestions to what may be causing this error?

```js
$.map(corporations_info, function(obj) {

    obj.id = obj.id || obj.corporation_id; // replace pk with your identifier

    $('#corporationName').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", obj.id).text(obj.name));

    return obj;

});

$('#extensionSetup')
    .find('[name="corporationName"]')
    .select2({

        dropdownCssClass: 'dropdown-inverse',
        placeholder: 'Select your Corporation',
        minimumResultsForSearch: 5

    })
    .change(function(e) {

        //$('#extensionSetup').formValidation('revalidateField', 'departmentName');

    })
    .end()
    .find('[name="departmentName"]')
    .select2({

        dropdownCssClass: 'dropdown-inverse',
        placeholder: 'Select your Department',
        minimumResultsForSearch: 5

    })
    .on('select2-close', function() {

        //$('#extensionSetup').formValidation('revalidateField', 'departmentName');

    })
    .change(function(e) {

        //$('#extensionSetup').formValidation('revalidateField', 'departmentName');

    })
    .end()
    .find('[name="employeeName"]')
    .select2({

        dropdownCssClass: 'dropdown-inverse',
        placeholder: 'Find your name',
        minimumResultsForSearch: 5,
        containerCssClass: 'select2-custom-search',
        dropdownCssClass: 'select2-custom-search'

    })
    .on('select2-opening', function() {

        console.log('opening');

    })
    .on('select2-open', function() {

        $('body')
            .find('.select2-container.select2-custom-search')
            .addClass('in-focus');

        $('body')
            .find('.select2-container.select2-custom-search')
            .find('.select2-choice')
            .find('.select2-arrow')
            .addClass('in-focus');

        $('body')
            .find('.select2-drop.select2-custom-search')
            .find('.select2-search')
            .find('input')
            .attr("placeholder", "Find your name");

        $('body')
            .find('.select2-container.select2-custom-search')
            .find('.select2-choice')
            .find('.select2-chosen')
            .hide();

    })
    .on('select2-select', function() {

        $('body')
            .find('.select2-drop.select2-custom-search')
            .find('.select2-search')
            .find('input')
            .attr("placeholder", "");

        $('body')
            .find('.select2-container.select2-custom-search')
            .find('.select2-choice')
            .find('.select2-chosen')
            .show();

    })
    .on('select2-close', function() {

        $('body')
            .find('.select2-container.select2-custom-search')
            .removeClass('in-focus');

        $('body')
            .find('.select2-container.select2-custom-search')
            .find('.select2-choice')
            .find('.select2-arrow')
            .removeClass('in-focus');

        $('body')
            .find('.select2-container.select2-custom-search')
            .find('.select2-choice')
            .find('.select2-chosen')
            .addClass('selected')
            .show();

        console.log('close');

    })
    .on('select2-close', function() {

        $('.select2-custom-search .select2-search input')
            .closest('.input-group')
            .find('.input-group-addon')
            .removeClass('in-focus');

    })
    .end()
    .formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        excluded: ':disabled',
        icon: {

            valid: 'material-icons valid-icon',
            invalid: 'material-icons invalid-icon',
            validating: 'material-icons validating-icon'

        },
        fields: {
            corporationName: {

                validators: {

                    callback: {

                        callback: function(value, validator, $field) {

                            if (value === '') {

                                return {

                                    valid: false,
                                    message: 'Please select the corporation you are associated with.',

                                };

                            }

                            return {

                                valid: true,

                            };

                        }
                    }

                }

            },
            departmentName: {

                validators: {

                    callback: {

                        callback: function(value, validator, $field) {

                            if (value === '') {

                                return {

                                    valid: false,
                                    message: 'Please select the department you are associated with.',

                                };

                            }

                            return {

                                valid: true,

                            };

                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    })
    // This event will be triggered when the field passes given validator
    .on('success.validator.fv', function(e, data) {
        // data.field     --> The field name
        // data.element   --> The field element
        // data.result    --> The result returned by the validator
        // data.validator --> The validator name

        if (data.field === 'corporationName') {

            $('#step3')
                .find('.dialog-warning.employees')
                .fadeOut()

            var selected_corporation_id = $('#corporationName').select2('data').id;
            var selected_corporation_name = $('#corporationName').select2('data').text;

            //var selected_department = $('#departmentName').select2('data').id;

            var departments_data = $.map(departments_info, function(obj) {

                if (obj.corporation_id === selected_corporation_id) {

                    return obj;

                }

            });

            if (!departments_data.length) {

                //console.info('YES!');

                console.warn('This corporation has no departments.');

                data.element
                    .closest('.form-group')
                    .removeClass('has-success')
                    .addClass('has-error');

                data.element
                    .closest('.form-group')
                    .find('.form-control-feedback')
                    .removeClass('valid-icon')
                    .addClass('invalid-icon');

                data.element
                    .closest('.form-group')
                    .find('.help-block')
                    .attr("data-fv-result", "INVALID");

                $.when($('.container-for-departmentName').fadeOut()).done(function() {

                    $('#step3')
                        .find('.dialog-warning.departments')
                        .fadeIn()
                        .find('.corporationName')
                        .text(selected_corporation_name);

                    $('#step3')
                        .find('.next-step')
                        .addClass('reload')
                        .text('Reload');

                    $('#extensionSetup')
                        .find('[name="departmentName"]')
                        .select2("enable", false);

                });

            } else {

                //console.warn('FUBAR!');

                $('#extensionSetup')
                    .find('[name="departmentName"]')
                    .closest('.form-group')
                    .removeClass('has-error');

                $('#extensionSetup')
                    .find('[name="departmentName"]')
                    .closest('.form-group')
                    .find('.form-control-feedback')
                    .removeClass('invalid-icon');

                $('#extensionSetup')
                    .find('[name="departmentName"]')
                    .closest('.form-group')
                    .find('.help-block')
                    .attr("data-fv-result", "");

                $.when($('#step3').find('.dialog-warning.departments').fadeOut()).done(function() {

                    $.when($('#extensionSetup')
                        .find('[name="departmentName"]')
                        .select2('data', null)
                        .find('option')
                        .each(function() {

                            if ($(this).val() === '') {

                                // Do nothing to keep first option intact 

                            } else {

                                $(this).remove();
                            }

                        })).done(function() {

                        $('#step3')
                            .find('.next-step')
                            .removeClass('reload')
                            .text('Save and Continue');

                        $.map(departments_data, function(obj) {

                            obj.id = obj.id || obj.department_id; // replace pk with your identifier

                            $('#departmentName').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", obj.id).text(obj.name));

                            return obj;

                        });

                        $('#extensionSetup')
                            .find('[name="departmentName"]')
                            .select2("enable", true);

                        $('.container-for-departmentName').fadeIn();

                    });

                });

            }

        }

        if (data.field === 'departmentName') {

            var selected_department_id = $('#departmentName').select2('data').id;
            var selected_department_name = $('#departmentName').select2('data').text;

            var coworkers_data = $.map(coworkers_info, function(obj) {

                if (obj.department_id === selected_department_id) {

                    return obj;

                }

            });

            if (!coworkers_data.length) {

                console.warn('This Department has no employees');

                data.element
                    .closest('.form-group')
                    .removeClass('has-success')
                    .addClass('has-error');

                data.element
                    .closest('.form-group')
                    .find('.form-control-feedback')
                    .removeClass('valid-icon')
                    .addClass('invalid-icon');

                data.element
                    .closest('.form-group')
                    .find('.help-block')
                    .attr("data-fv-result", "INVALID");

                $('#step3')
                    .find('.dialog-warning.employees')
                    .fadeIn()
                    .find('.departmentName')
                    .text(selected_department_name);

                $('#step3')
                    .find('.next-step')
                    .addClass('reload')
                    .text('Reload');

                $('#extensionSetup')
                    .find('[name="employeeName"]')
                    .select2("enable", false);



            } else {

                data.element
                    .closest('.form-group')
                    .removeClass('has-error');

                data.element
                    .closest('.form-group')
                    .find('.form-control-feedback')
                    .removeClass('invalid-icon');

                data.element
                    .closest('.form-group')
                    .find('.help-block')
                    .attr("data-fv-result", "");

                $.when($('#step3')
                    .find('.dialog-warning.employees')
                    .fadeOut()).done(function() {

                    $.when($('#extensionSetup')
                        .find('[name="employeeName"]')
                        .select2('data', null)
                        .find('option')
                        .each(function() {

                            if ($(this).val() === '') {

                                // Do nothing to keep first option intact 

                            } else {

                                $(this).remove();
                            }

                        })).done(function() {

                        $('#step3')
                            .find('.next-step')
                            .removeClass('reload')
                            .text('Save and Continue');

                        $.map(coworkers_data, function(obj) {

                            obj.id = obj.id || obj.mobile_phone; // replace pk with your identifier

                            $('#employeeName').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", obj.id).text(obj.first_name + ' ' + obj.last_name));

                            return obj;

                        });

                        $('#extensionSetup')
                            .find('[name="employeeName"]')
                            .select2("enable", true);

                    });

                });

            }

        }

    })
    .bootstrapWizard({
        tabClass: 'nav nav-tabs',
        onTabClick: function(tab, navigation, index) {
            return validateTab(index);
        },
        onNext: function(tab, navigation, index) {
            var numTabs = $('#extensionSetup').find('.tab-pane').length,
                isValidTab = validateTab(index - 1);
            if (!isValidTab) {
                return false;
            }

            if (index === numTabs) {
                // We are at the last tab

                // Uncomment the following line to submit the form using the defaultSubmit() method
                // $('#extensionSetup').formValidation('defaultSubmit');

                // For testing purpose
                $('#completeModal').modal();
            }

            return true;
        },
        onPrevious: function(tab, navigation, index) {
            return validateTab(index + 1);
        },
        onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
            // Update the label of Next button when we are at the last tab
            var numTabs = $('#extensionSetup').find('.tab-pane').length;
            $('#extensionSetup')
                .find('.next-step ')
                .removeClass('disabled') // Enable the Next button
                .find('a')
                .html(index === numTabs - 1 ? 'Install' : 'Next');
        }
    });

function validateTab(index) {
    var fv = $('#extensionSetup').data('formValidation'), // FormValidation instance
        // The current tab
        $tab = $('#extensionSetup').find('.tab-pane').eq(index);

    // Validate the container
    fv.validateContainer($tab);

    var isValidStep = fv.isValidContainer($tab);
    if (isValidStep === false || isValidStep === null) {
        // Do not jump to the target tab
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You might want `.attr('id')` if `select2()` is chainable.

Comment: @Tushar That just results in `dev.js:972 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2(...).attr is not a function` on load.